# Python - x axis labels and ticks

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have an array of data (length of 365, Max temperature for each day of year).
I am making a simple line plot with days of year on x-axis and temperature value on the y-axis. The snippet of relevant code is below with the output image.

```
fig = plt.figure()
temp_data = temp_total[:]
plt.plot(temp_data-273.15)
plt.ylabel('Temperature (C)',size=12)
plt.xlabel('Day of Year',size=12)
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXkoA.png]

Instead of the x-axis having ticks for each day of the year, I would like to plot each month on the x-axis. Jan, Feb, Mar, etc.

I have not found anything that works yet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Due to months having unequal number of days it's probably best to use actual dates to plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)


temp_data = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(365))+273.15
dates = [datetime(2018,1,1)+timedelta(days=i) for i in range(len(temp_data))]

plt.plot(dates, temp_data-273.15)

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))

plt.ylabel('Temperature (C)',size=12)
plt.xlabel('Day of Year',size=12)

plt.show()
```

[image]